# How to assign the VMware license key to a bootable USB (ISO image)

Tags: usb-flash-drive, vmware, bootable-media, esxi

I have created a bootable USB using [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/), but for every new installation I need to go to the Host and manually assign the license.

Is there a way to create a bootable USB with the license already assigned?